# Dataerror: No numeric types to aggregate while taking mean

Tags: dataframe, pandas-groupby, mean, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataframe "**delhi_onehot**" which I created using one-hot encoding and I am trying to get mean using groupby function on column "Neighbourhood" which is of type 'object'. And so I am getting this error

> No numeric types to aggregate.

I am new to this. I also tried to convert it into float using pd.to_numeric but it is showing me error

> Neighbourhood column is of string type.

[image]

I want my code to work like this which I did in my previous project:

[image]

Comment: Please share a sample of data with expected output.

Comment: Done @MayankPorwal